# How can I print the absolute path of a list of files in Python?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to print a list from files in my script. However, the following code prints the file names instead of the absolute path.

I need the path while the files are located in another folder. I already tried some other functions without success.

Here's my code:

```
ch = []

for file in os.listdir("URL"):
    if file.endswith("ch4.TXT"):
        ch.append(file)

        print ch
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `os.path.join()` to join the components, and to use `os.getcwd()` to get the current working directory.

I changed the name `file` to `fname`.  On Python 2 `file` is an alias to `open`.

```
import os
import os.path

ch = []
wd = os.getcwd()
for fname in os.listdir("URL"):
    if fname.endswith("ch4.TXT"):
        ch.append(os.path.join(wd, "URL", fname))

print ch
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` or `pathlib` module to get the abspath of the file.

```
import os
import sys


search_path = sys.argv[1] # expects an abspath to dir
ch = []
for file in os.listdir(search_path):
    if file.endswith("ch4.TXT"):
        abs_path = os.path.join(search_path, file)
        ch.append(abs_path)
print ch
```

Comment: This might give incorrect results, it assumes that the python script is stored in our current directory, `__file__` gives the location of the python script, not the current directory.  Also, you have `abs_path` and `abspath`.

Comment: @cdarke Otherwise he has to pass the abspath of the directory he want listed as the argument

Comment: I know we could use `os.getcwd` to get the current working directory. But personally, i'm against it's use :)

Comment: Why are you against its use?